# Flutter yearly local notifications

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I want to develop a birthday app and it should send a notification every year per person.

I am already using the 'flutter_local_notifications' package and it got the feature to periodically show a notification, but not yearly. At the moment I am just determine the next birthday of each person and everytime a user opens the app, the notifications are scheduled. But if somebody doesn't open up the app in a year, he won't be notificated.

Have anyone a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround if you want to implement yearly notifications with 'flutter_local_notifications' package:

```
   import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
   import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
   import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

   List<tz.TZDateTime> scheduledDateTimes = [];
   int numberOfYears = 7; // Define how many years you want this notification to show
   int notificationID = Random().nextInt(1000000);
   DateTime startDate = DateTime.now(); // Define the starting date of this yearly notification
  
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++) {
      scheduledDateTimes.add(tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, date.year + i, date.month,
        date.day);
   } 
  
   scheduledDateTimes.asMap().forEach((index, dateTime) async {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          int.parse("$notificationID$index"),
          title,
          'Notification title',
          dateTime,
          notificationDetails,
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
    });
```

Also, please take into consideration that number of local notifications you can schedule is limited to 50 for android, and 64 for iOS.